# I'd like to force a 502 or 504 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using .htaccess how can I force only my IP address to return a 502 or 504 error? I want to test cloudflare's always on services, and they said that if I could generate these errors, I'd be able to see if the always on technology was working for my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the only consideration for [Always Online](http://cloudflare.tenderapp.com/kb/troubleshooting/why-doesnt-always-online-display-all-pages-of-my-site-when-my-server-is-down) to kick in. It also depends on search engine caching and some other factors.

Note: We're working on a better version that basically eliminates most of the limitations.

Comment: I know that's not the only consideration. I think I spoke with you in support, that's why I'm here. I want to test always online before the big day our website goes on national tv.